# Changing input type checkbox color into a green color in Angular 15

Tags: angular, checkbox, primeng

I did not find anywhere how to put a green color on a input type checkbox using Angular .I also use Tailwind but that is not relevant. I have this component : Component.HTML:  `<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-success focus:ring-success checked:bg-success" (change)="applyFilters(filter.value, $event)" />` The color never changes from blue . I tried a lot of different properties but nothing seems to work. I tried to change the to green from blue to the check box and it remained blue .

Comment: When you say "the color of the checkbox" what exactly do you mean? You are applying a `text-success` class, which I assume would make text green, but a checkbox has no next to style. It's a checkbox and those styles either come from your browser defaults or your `form-checkbox` clas. This is not really an Angular question at all, you are asking a CSS question

Comment: Are you using PrimeNG checkbox? Cause I see you tag *primeng*, but your checkbox element didn't apply the PrimeNG checkbox component

Comment: I have primeng installed in my project.By modifying the checkbox color i mean the back ground color of the box that comes by default blue . I want to have it green , but I don t know what property should i use in css to make that possible .

Answer (score 0):

For simple input you can use accent-color, i'm not sure if this is what you need but you can try this one

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  accent-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-success focus:ring-success checked:bg-success" (change)="applyFilters(filter.value, $event)" />
```